# Change color of cursor, for the measure tool

Tags: measurement

Is there a way to change the color of that circle cursor, for the measure tool?

[image]

Comment: Hmm ... How did you get the circle visible and what is a purpose of it? My cursor looks differently too. What blender version you use? Or ... what measure tool you use?

Comment: This tool bpy.ops.wm.tool_set_by_id(name="builtin.annotate")
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/wz2eqc8670e6z5w25t7kf/2023-07-06_22-06-41_Blender_-DDropboxGitLabrestaurant_livingston_Encry_blender.png?rlkey=v4jzbsp7s2oa51w0yse45hlhk&dl=0
Blender 3.5

Comment: Hm ... than I can't help ... I can just repeat my comment above ... You can edit your Q with info about your operation system ... btw are you in Object mode?  ...I still can t get it what is the purpose if the circle.